# Get jquery selector from object parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
box_tpv1 = {
    box:$("#box_tpv1"),
    open:function(mensaje,f_ok,f_x){
        this.box.show()
    }
}
```

And when I call this **box_tpv1.open()** won't work, but If I write inside open function $("#box_tpv1").show() it works.

Comment: You have to use closures. `this` in your example refers to the anonymous function.

Comment: Try to add a `console.log(this.box);` in open function to see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `box_tpv1` is a singleton object, which cannot be further instantiated using `new`. Which means the value of `this` is insignificant.

You might as well simply call `box_tpv1.box.show()` inside the `open` function.

Comment: It won't work, and how It would be instatiated with new? I don't understand very well objects in javascript :(

Comment: This should clarify things regarding objects in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

there might be issues on the context this function is being called and that depends upon from where are you calling this function from 
try calling like this

```
box_tpv1.open.call(box_tpv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I solved it this way, I can get with this.box the value inside the object methods but doesnt work the jquery selector, if I do that it works

```
box_tpv1 = {
    box:"#box_tpv1",
    open:function(mensaje,f_ok,f_x){
        $(this.box).show()
    }
}
```